# Filter array of objects within another array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have the following `array` of objects

```
[
  {
    weakness: [
      "Fire",
      "Flying",
      "Ice",
      "Psychic"
    ],
    id: 1,
    type: [
      "grass",
      "poison"
    ]
  },
  {
    weight: 28.7,
    weakness: [
      "Fire",
      "Flying",
      "Ice",
      "Psychic"
    ],
    id: 2,
    type: [
      "grass",
      "poison"
    ]
  },
  {
    weakness: [
      "Fire",
      "Psychic",
      "Flying",
      "Ice"
    ],
    id: 3,
    type: [
      "grass",
      "poison"
    ]
  },
  {
    weakness: [
      "Fire",
      "Flying",
      "Ice",
      "Psychic"
    ],
    id: 3,
    type: [
      "grass",
      "poison"
    ]
  }
]
```

I want to filter according to the type, for example the type "grass"

However, I'm not able to enter the `array` to do this manipulation

I have tried to do the filtering with the filter, but without success

Comment: please add your try.

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case your input data may be malformed you might want to add some defensive checks to check if the object has a `type` key beforehand:

```
const grassArray = array.filter(obj => obj.hasOwnProperty('type') &&
                                       Array.isArray(obj.type) &&
                                       obj['type'].includes('grass'));
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an array with 4 objects and the last one is without grass. You can get the output with this filter.

```js
let a = [
  {
    weakness: [
      "Fire",
      "Flying",
      "Ice",
      "Psychic"
    ],
    id: 1,
    type: [
      "grass",
      "poison"
    ]
  },
  {
    weight: 28.7,
    weakness: [
      "Fire",
      "Flying",
      "Ice",
      "Psychic"
    ],
    id: 2,
    type: [
      "grass",
      "poison"
    ]
  },
  {
    weakness: [
      "Fire",
      "Psychic",
      "Flying",
      "Ice"
    ],
    id: 3,
    type: [
      "grass",
      "poison"
    ]
  },
  {
    weakness: [
      "Fire",
      "Flying",
      "Ice",
      "Psychic"
    ],
    id: 4,
    type: [
      "poison"
    ]
  }
]

console.log(a.filter(e => e.type.findIndex(e => e === 'grass') > -1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out to filter by using the includes method for the nested array :

```
arr.filter(item=>item.type.includes("grass"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your array has grass in all of them. If I remove a few, you get this

```js
const arr = [{ weakness: [ "Fire", "Flying", "Ice", "Psychic" ], id: 1, 
  type: [ "poison" ] }, { weight: 28.7, weakness: [ "Fire", "Flying", "Ice", "Psychic" ], id: 2, 
  type: [ "poison" ] }, { weakness: [ "Fire", "Psychic", "Flying", "Ice" ], id: 3, 
  type: [ "grass", "poison" ] }, { weakness: [ "Fire", "Flying", "Ice", "Psychic" ], id: 3, 
  type: [ "grass", "poison" ] } ];
 
const grass = arr
  .filter(({type}) => type
    .filter(item => item.includes("grass")).length>0)

console.log(grass)
```